# date.timestamp not found in python?

Tags: python, datetime

After changing the import as a from-import
i'm running into this error:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
today = date.today()
from time import mktime
from feedparser import feedparser
import settings

def check_calendar():
    d = feedparser.parse(settings.personal_calendar_feed)
    for entry in d.entries:
        if(date.fromtimestamp(mktime(entry.date_parsed))==today):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File computer.py", line 734, in <module>
    check_calendar()
  File "computer.py", line 210, in check_calendar
    if(date.fromtimestamp(mktime(entry.date_parsed))==today):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

Comment: @Abhijit: `date` is not a module. It is a class within the `datetime` module

Comment: @jdi: I misread the first line and missed the `from datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'

in the error. Apparently you may have a function named "date" in your code. Since Python allows you to use any name, and new conflicting names will override the older ones.

Instead, when python can't find a function from a module or object, it usually says type object has no attribute or module has no attribute, like if I want to call "fromtimes" :

> type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'fromtimes'

You may want to check your code carefully again.

Comment: you're definitively right! Now i'm gonna rename this function. btw the exception wasn't very descriptive about this...

Answer (score 3):

It is highly possible that you have redeclared `date` as function `def date():` earlier in code. Otherwise it makes no sense.